# Why is the Horseman of Death "allergic" to sunlight, but not the Horseman of War?

Tags: sleepy-hollow

In the show "Sleepy Hollow", is there an in-universe reason/answer as to why the Horseman of Death (The Headless Horseman) can't stand the sunlight, whilst the other Horseman (Henry) can ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### The Horseman of Death is, in fact, very dead. Henry was dead and sold his soul to Moloch. His powers are far less than Death's and thus his limitations are far less as well. This difference is why each can be handled and treated in completely different ways.

- Note that both could be held within the ensorcelled room, so their supernatural origins allow them to be confined similarly.
- The Horseman of Death is dead. His resurrection while giving him a host of supernatural abilities, such as seeing without a head, heating an axe and making it super-sharp, absorbing normal bullets like raindrops, and did I mention, using firearms without a head.
- Returning to the realm of the living required supernatural influences and thus those influences leave him vulnerable to a host of anti-supernatural forces including, blessed weapons, consecrated bullets, and the slayer of many things un-naturally alive, sunlight.
- Henry, the Horseman of War, on the other hand appears quite alive and while may have magical abilities, he is not as far gone as the Horseman of Death, who is supernaturally vital despite having no head and complete invulnerability to normal weaponry.
- This series, so far, has admitted to playing fast and loose with their supernatural menaces whose like is rarely seen on broadcast television. They admit to creating things on the fly to keep the viewership off-balance and guessing.

Comment: Your synopsis says "Henry was dead" but your body says "Henry...appears quite alive."  I find this confusing; perhaps it can be reworded?